# array length is 0 even though it has values

Tags: javascript, arrays

I query a firebase database and I get the results, which I push into an array, cause I need then to cut duplicate results.
everything seem to work, but the length I get is 0, even though data is there.

```
let interests = [
  '-KpUpVi7-2W_JmR16HuC',
  '-KpUpYwC_FRulbXZnULK',
  '-Kpd3J9gNECwWSG6xAvt',
  '-KpUpbP3AGKs28McNrBh'
]
let finalArray = [];
interests.forEach((interest) => {
  this.hangoutsService.getInterestUsers(interest)
  .subscribe(
    (res) => {
      //console.log('the results: ', res)
      res.forEach((uid) => {
        //console.log(uid)
        finalArray.push(uid)
      })

    }
  )
})
console.log('final array: ',finalArray)
console.log('final array length: ',finalArray.length)
```

and this is the method it calls:

```
  getInterestUsers(interest){
  return this.db.object(`usersPerInterest/${interest}`)
    .map((r) => {
        return Object.keys(r)
    })
}
```

I attach the screenshot of the console:
[image]

What am I missing here?

Comment: the console lies ... hover over the white `i` in the blue square :p (next to `final array`)

Comment: I would guess the completion handler in the `subscribe` call is executed asynchronously. When you print the `finalArray` and its length (synchronously immediately after _setting up_ the subscription), it has yet to be populated by the subscription callback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using callbacks. But the array prints before getting the response from callback.

```
let interests = [
  '-KpUpVi7-2W_JmR16HuC',
  '-KpUpYwC_FRulbXZnULK',
  '-Kpd3J9gNECwWSG6xAvt',
  '-KpUpbP3AGKs28McNrBh'
]
let finalArray = [];
interests.forEach((interest) => {
  this.hangoutsService.getInterestUsers(interest)
  .subscribe(
    (res) => {
      //console.log('the results: ', res)
      res.forEach((uid) => {
        //console.log(uid)
        finalArray.push(uid)
      })
    console.log('final array: ',finalArray)
    console.log('final array length: ',finalArray.length)
    }
  )
})
```

However, to do this in a better way, use promises.

Comment: can you explain what you have changed please?

Answer (score 0):

You're console logging the array length immediate outside of your asynchronize callback function. when the console log is executing, the callback function is not finished yet.

```
console.log('final array: ',finalArray)
console.log('final array length: ',finalArray.length)
```

That is why it is getting an empty array. You can't get the proper result of a asynchronize function's result this way, you've to put the console log inside the asynchronize function.

```
let finalArray = [];
interests.forEach((interest) => {
  this.hangoutsService.getInterestUsers(interest)
  .subscribe(
    (res) => {
      //console.log('the results: ', res)
      res.forEach((uid) => {
        //console.log(uid)
        finalArray.push(uid)
      })
        console.log('final array: ',finalArray)
       console.log('final array length: ',finalArray.length)
    }
  )
})
```